# Retrieve Project and all it's tasks by Id

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, project-server

I'm new to SharePoint, I have been trying to retrieve a single Project and all its Tasks by doing the following:

```
https://servername.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')/Tasks
```

I have also tried to retrieve a Project by doing this:

```
https://servername.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

This is the error that I receive:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "1000, Microsoft.ProjectServer.PJClientCallableException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "This project either does not exist, or has been deleted.  Only QueueJobs can be accessed from a deleted project."
        }
    } }
```

Which is not true because I'm able to get all the projects by doing this:

```
https://servername.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$top=100
```

Also, if I don't use the `$top` this is what the query returns:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": []
    }
}
```

why is that?

I'm doing this in Postman. I have looked through the documentation and haven't come across anything. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hmm... not sure what is going on with the non-`$top` query returning nothing, but at least as far as your main queries go, the syntax looks correct.  Have you verified that you have the correct GUID for the project ID?  Also, are these projects published?  If so, have you considered using the `/_api/ProjectData/` endpoint?

Comment: @DylanCristy the GUID is the same as the one retrieved from 'all projects' so it should work.
The projects are published I have tried ProjectData and this is what I get - 20010, Microsoft.ProjectServer.PJClientCallableException, GeneralSecurityAccessDenied.

Comment: To access the `ProjectData` endpoint, you need to be in the Portfolio Managers group.  If you're getting the ID from the results of the 'all projects' query, that certainly is odd.  I wonder if you could flip the query around to use the ID as a filter, so something like `/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$filter=Id eq guid'xxxxxxx'&$select=Tasks&$expand=Tasks` ?

Comment: @DylanCristy the $filter only works on the name of the project and not the Id.

Comment: Are you sure?  It seems like you are using Project Online, so maybe it is a difference between Project Online and on-premises (I am working with Project Server 2016 on-prem), but that query using the Id as the filter and then selecting and expanding Tasks worked for me just now in Postman.

Comment: @DylanCristy that worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try flipping the query around to use the Project ID as a filter, like:

```
/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$filter=Id eq guid'xxxxxxxx'&$select=Tasks&$expand=Tasks
```